# How do I mark a video as watched with Youtube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a C# program I wrote using the Youtube API V3 that manages my channel's videos.
I already have all the OAuth 2.0 stuff sorted out and I'm looking for a way to tell Youtube that the authenticated account watched the video.
The reason being that I use the "watched" feature to determine which of the videos in my feed is the last one I actually watched.

Is there a way to do that?
Or is it purposefully not in the API because it messes with the view count?

Of course I checked Google and Google's API reference first, didn't find anything.

Comment: you are right in your last question, because youtube only counts video as watched when time spend on watching video equals video length, can't you make such feature in your program that will automatically mark viewed video as watched (only for you app).

Comment: @mastah I don't think what you're saying is true.
Even if I watch a video for a few seconds, regardless of the video length Youtube marks it as watched.
I didn't understand your last sentence - you're suggesting I implement my own video history in my app and manage it there?
Even if the only way is to watch the video, is there a way to "watch" the video using the API?